# Best way to render OpenType font preview in PHP

Tags: php, opentype

I am trying to render OpenType text (with ligatures... which is why I am using OTF vs TTF).  I can't find a good way to do so in PHP.  Is there a Cairo/Pango library that is easy to install to do this for PHP?  Or am I going about this all wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This makes no sense, so I think you're misunderstanding something about fonts: ligatures are a feature from OpenType, the specification. There are two kinds of OpenType font: OT-with-TTF-outlines, and OT-with-CFF-blocks, the first is typically called `whatever.ttf` and the second `whatever.otf` but they're *both* OpenType fonts, and *both* support all OpenType features. As for rendering: don't make PHP do something it's not good at, make it call a process/script that can make images for you with the fonts you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib to get the outlines, I didn't tested it but it looks like you can even get an SVG.